# How to submit a form with a modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, redux-form

I have a form made in react, using reduxForm that when submitting, opens a modal for validation,
I put this modal in a component and if the user confirm the button in modal, the main form needs to be submitted and the modal closed.

I try with `!show` on onCancel, but that didn't work.

This is the main form:

```
<Form className="user-form" readOnly={isReadOnly}>
    <ConfirmModal show={showModal} />

    ...

    <Button
        type="button"
        onClick={submitForm}
    />
</Form>
```

Here is the validation to open the modal

```
const submitForm = () => {
    openModal ? showModal : isReadOnly ? () => {} : handleSubmit();
};
```

This is the modal component

```
const ConfirmModal = (show) => {
    const onConfirm = () => {
      console.log('submit form');
    };
    const onCancel = () => {
      console.log('cancel form');
    };
  
    return (
      <Modal open={show}>
        <Body>
          // Modal Content
        </Body>
          <Button onClick={() => onCancel()}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => onConfirm()}>
            Submit
          </Button>
      </Modal>
    );
  };

  export default ConfirmModal;
```

How can I submit the form through the modal submit?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the button tag that should submit the form inside a form element with onSubmit={submitForm} and set the type of the Button to submit

```
<Form onSubmit={submitForm}>
   <Button type="submit" onClick={() => onCancel()}>
   Cancel
   </Button>
</Form>
```

Comment: But I need to submit the form through the open modal